# Gradle 1.11 Could not resolve commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am new to gradle and I am simply trying to build a sample project provided in the gradle 1.11 download. For some reason whenever I need to access an external repo I am getting status code 401 back from Maven's servers. I have searched around and not been able to find an answer to this problem. Can anyone help me figure this out? Whenever I attempt to build the project this is what I get back:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.

  > Could not resolve commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.
  >   Required by:
  >     :quickstart:1.0
  >   Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: authenticationrequired
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.97 secs

I am not sure what authentication I need in order to access the repo. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: (Forst Post Review) You might want to reformat the output a bit. If you intend the while thing by 4 blanks it should look like a single uniformly formatted block

Comment: Any sample `gradle` script demonstrating the behavior might be also useful.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your response. I figured out that the problem is because I am behind a firewall that is blocking my access to Maven Central.

Answer (score 0):

Add `jcenter()` as a repo:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```